Vertx(4.5.7) OutputUnit does not give validation messages when schema validation fails
I was trying to use Vertx's JSON Schema standards for validating the following schema:
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$id": "https://example.com/create.stockincdecevent.schema.json",
  "title": "Create-Stock-Inc-Dec-event",
  "description": "Schema for the event to request a stock inc dec operation",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "userMetaData": {
      "type": "object",
      "description": "Meta attributes used by the user of the system",
      "properties": {
        "userId": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The user ID of the connected client"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "userId"
      ]
    },
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "description": "The data that has to be processed.",
      "properties": {
        "itemID": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "The item for which the stock has to be deducted."
        },
        "stockCount": {
          "type": "number",
          "description": "stock count to deduct."
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "itemID",
        "stockCount"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "userMetaData",
    "data"
  ]
}

Data to validate the above schema:
{
  "userMetaData": {
    "userId": "user-1"
  },
  "data": {
    "itemID": "Item-1",
    "stockCount": 1
  }
}

Code to validate
OutputUnit schemaValidateResponse = Validator
  .create(schema, new JsonSchemaOptions().setBaseUri("https://example.com").setDraft(Draft.DRAFT202012))
  .validate(dataToValidate)

The OutputUnit returns true for the above instance but, If I give an invalid instance, the OutputUnit does not have any error messages.
{
  "userMetaData": {
    "userId": "user-1"
  },
  "data": {
    "itemID": "Item-1"
  }
}

Any leads will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

does the OutputUnit result change for the invalid instance?  Does it return false?

Yes. It returns false but error list is empty!

you may need to provide more code sample where you think you're having an issue.  the small snippet doesn't have enough context

schemaValidateResponse.getErrors() returns null.

Per the 2020-12 specification, error messages are recommended but not required.  I agree that not including an error message is a bad user experience.  I'd file an issue with the library to see if you can get them to add one.
In the meantime, you can use https://json-everything.net/json-schema (my online playground), which will give you the error messages you're looking for.  (Note that the output format my site gives is actually the proposed format for the next release of the spec, not 2020-12.)
Here's what it gives for the instance you posted:
{
  "valid": false,
  "evaluationPath": "",
  "schemaLocation": "https://example.com/create.stockincdecevent.schema.json#",
  "instanceLocation": "",
  "details": [
    {
      "valid": true,
      "evaluationPath": "/properties/userMetaData",
      "schemaLocation": "https://example.com/create.stockincdecevent.schema.json#/properties/userMetaData",
      "instanceLocation": "/userMetaData",
      "annotations": {
        "description": "Meta attributes used by the user of the system",
        "properties": [
          "userId"
        ]
      },
      "details": [
        {
          "valid": true,
          "evaluationPath": "/properties/userMetaData/properties/userId",
          "schemaLocation": "https://example.com/create.stockincdecevent.schema.json#/properties/userMetaData/properties/userId",
          "instanceLocation": "/userMetaData/userId",
          "annotations": {
            "description": "The user ID of the connected client"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "valid": false,
      "evaluationPath": "/properties/data",
      "schemaLocation": "https://example.com/create.stockincdecevent.schema.json#/properties/data",
      "instanceLocation": "/data",
      "errors": {
        "required": "Required properties [\"stockCount\"] are not present"
      },
      "details": [
        {
          "valid": true,
          "evaluationPath": "/properties/data/properties/itemID",
          "schemaLocation": "https://example.com/create.stockincdecevent.schema.json#/properties/data/properties/itemID",
          "instanceLocation": "/data/itemID",
          "annotations": {
            "description": "The item for which the stock has to be deducted."
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

The error you're looking for is:

Required properties ["stockCount"] are not present

